# How do I write code in C# to print the given string in the descending order of size of the word

Tags: c#

The given string is `first last middle begin end` ; I should get the output like `middle begin first last end`?

Answer (score 1):

This will do your job. Split and then sort by length.

```
string s = "first last middle begin end";
string[] words = s.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Length).ToArray();
```

Comment: final step. join them to one string

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a sorting problem. Figure out how to split the string into individual words, then sort by length, and then recombine them into one string.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate the original String by Char ' ' (empty Space).
Then save these separations in String Array, or I prefer a List.

e.g.

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
```

Then you can loop through Array/List by Item-Length, display the words, delete the entry, loop again, ...

Answer (score 0):

The result in your example also seems to be sorting alphabetically after sorting the words by length in descending order.  Here is some code that uses Linq to perform both levels of the sort:

```
        string s = "first last middle begin end";
        s = string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').OrderByDescending(item => item.Length).ThenBy(item => item).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```